# Why is background app refresh a synonym of multitasking?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Multitasking is using several apps at the same time.

Whereas background app refresh is the app refreshing in the background even when not in use.

Why are they synonyms?

Comment: Multitaksing is **not** running several apps at the same time.  It's running several *tasks* at the same time, thus the name.   Background refresh, by it's very definition is performing a task *in the background* (like fetching email) while in the foreground something else is happening (like surfing the web).